# Understanding Gradient Tape with mini batches

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent

In the below example taken from [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/),  I want to understand how `grads` is computed. Does the gradient `grads` corresponds to the average gradient computed using the batch `(x_batch_train, y_batch_train)`? In other words, does the algorithm computes the gradient, with respect to each variable, using every sample in the mini batch and then average them to get `grads`?

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):

        # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
        # during the forward pass, which enables auto-differentiation.
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            # Run the forward pass of the layer.
            # The operations that the layer applies
            # to its inputs are going to be recorded
            # on the GradientTape.
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

            # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)

        # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
        # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

        # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
        # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

Answer (score 0):

Default value is `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` .

Read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Reduction?hl=en) .

Answer (score 0):

Your suppositions are correct.

The documentation provided by DachuanZhao shows as well, that the sum of the elements in the batch are averaged.